# Use of "would" in sentence

Tags: modal-verbs

What does "*would*" mean in the following sentences?

> That picture **would** look better on the other wall.

> It **would** be nice to see more of Ray and Barbara.

> Six o'clock **would** be a good time to meet.

> We can't all stay in a hotel. It **would** be very expensive.

Comment: What are you asking here?

Comment: @DanielRoseman What does "would" mean in the above sentences?

Answer (score -1):

It is the hypothetical version of "will" indicating the future.

That picture will look better on the other wall. (prediction/assumption of future)

That picture would look better on the other wall. (hypothetical future)

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what "hypothetical future" is? Six o'clock would be a good time to meet.

Comment: "Will look better" - I am definitely planning to move the picture. "Would look better" - I am imagining how it would look if I were to move it.